# Change onInterceptTouchEvent result back to false after already returning true

Tags: android

I have a `FrameLayout` and inside it I have a `GoogleMap` object. I wanted to limit user zoom levels to be between certain zoom levels. (This is not a question about Google Maps but a general one about `onInterceptTouchEvent` behavior.)

So in the `FrameLayout` I've overridden `onInterceptTouchEvent` and when the user pinch zoom I detect it using `ScaleGestureDetector` and check if the map zoom level is in between the desire values.

If they are, `onInterceptTouchEvent` returns `false` and the sibling view (Google Maps) perform the zoom regularly.

If they are not, I return `true` and by that the sibling views does not receive the gesture.

However this creates a behavior that if you pinch-zoom out to the maximum and then immediately pinch-zoom in (without lifting your fingers), the view will not zoom in.

This is because `onInterceptTouchEvent` no longer gets called (because I've returned true earlier) and there is no way for me to pass the even to the sibling views.

If I lift my fingers and then pinch-zoom in, it works again.

Is there anyway I can ask the view to recall `onInterceptTouchEvent` all over again?

Comment: afaik all you can do is to override dispatchTouchEvent and make your own event dispatching

Comment: Can I maybe manually call the onTouchEvent of my sibling directly ? (If I receive no more comments I will test and let you know)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by implementing dispatchTouchEvent on the viewgroup and returning 'true' when you want to cancel the request.

Some general information about why it works:

In Android, this is the order of events being called (from first to last):

1. User touch screen
2. The Activity receives dispatchTouchEvent()
3. The ViewGroup receive dispatchTouchEvent()
4. The View receives dispatchTouchEvent()
   then it continues by going back up:
5. The View receives onTouchEvent()
6. The ViewGroup receives onTouchEvent()
7. The Activity receives onTouchEvent()

If you return 'true' during any of the phases, it will stop the event from continuing in the chain.

Its good enough and works.

Thanks.